# Locating instantiated prototype beans

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am creating multiple beans of the same class like this:

```
(CardImpl)ctx.getBean("Card", driver, webElement)
```

where `CardImpl` is defined like this:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurabelBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class CardImpl implements Card
```

So here I end up with multiple instantiated beans that have different properties (as I provide variable `webElement` to the constructor as you can see above).

I do not use these beans immediately after their creation but need them at a later stage of my flow. So here is my question:

**Q**: How do I find or/and refer to an already created bean (that is sitting somewhere in the Spring container) using one if its properties as search argument?

**P.S.** If such approach is not considered a good practice please feel free to point to any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly don't use the `ctx.getBean`. Only use this as a last result. You shouldn't be relying on the context for retrieving beans, instead you use dependency injection in Spring.

Generally I don't think the reset of your application should know or care about the scope of the bean they are interacting with. Whether it is session, singleton or prototype, this will not affect their interface.

There are ways to do what you are doing but it's pretty much going to be the same as having a static `Map<String, CardImpl>` and pulling instances out of that. This breaks the whole purpose of Spring dependency injection. You could have this map in a singleton bean this would be the least terrible I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. While I agree with your point here, I just couldn't come up with another solution. These beans that I am talking about here are used to store Selenium WebElements with dynamically instantiated properties. Basically if there is another way I can provide an additional parameter to a bean that is going to be injected that would be all I need. However according to my research, the only way to accomplish that is by using the `getBean()` method.